# MVC4 - during post controller action, the WebSecurity.CurrentUserId is losing it's value, and becomes -1

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Somehow, in this controller, after the SaveChanges, the CurrentUserId  becomes -1. 
The data post works, and the CurrentUserId has it's logged in value (example 8888), but after the SQL insert, the WebSecurity.CurrentUserId becomes -1. Any clue? During debug I can't find where and why.

```
    // POST: /Account/Edit
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Edit(UserProfile model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            using (var context = new dbContext())
            {
                var id = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
                var account = context.UserProfiles.Find(id);
                UpdateModel(account);
                context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
            }


        }
        else
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you doing autoincrement

Comment: `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId == -1` indicates that there is no currently logged in user.  Where is the value changing? In the same controller, right after the save changes and before the redirect? Or on the page you are redirecting to?

Answer (score 0):

that will always return -1,  what you need is the below code

```
 int currentuserid = WebSecurity.GetUserId(username);
```

You can then validate that the userid above, matches the userid in the model, in order to prevent users, changing other users code

as Additional.  I use this in my Base Controller:

```
public int GetUserId()
    {
        var userid = "0";

        if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.Identity.Name != null)
        {
            var membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
            if (membershipUser != null)
            {
                if (membershipUser.ProviderUserKey != null)
                {
                    userid = membershipUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        return Convert.ToInt32(userid);
    }
```

Comment: Nope, not what I needed. Your syg

Comment: Nope, not what I needed. Your suggestion - allow to edit only your own stuff - has been implemented with a customAttribute [AuthorizeCreator].